# Test is not turning red when it should be | Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial | 10.4.1 Exercise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The actual exercise question:
"By issuing a PATCH request directly to the user path as shown in Listing 10.56, verify that the admin attribute isn’t editable through the web. To be sure your test is covering the right thing, your first step should be to add admin to the list of permitted parameters in user_params so that the initial test is red."

So I placed the admin attribute in my params hash that permits specific attributes in the users_controller.rb:

```
   def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:admin, :name, :email, :password,
                                  :password_confirmation) #params hash that permits specific attributes
   end
```

And I ran the test in the users_controller_test.rb:

```
  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
    @other_user = users(:archer)
  end

  test "should not allow the admin attribute to be edited via the web" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    assert_not @other_user.admin?
    patch user_path(@other_user), params: {
                              user: { password:              @other_user.password,
                                      password_confirmation: @other_user.password,
                                      admin: true } } #it's true because the user is trying to send a patch request saying they are the admin now
    assert_not @other_user.reload.admin?
  end
```

But yet my test still turns green when it should be turning red. Anyone have any idea why that may be? Is something else in my source code affecting this test?

Haven't pushed my changes into heroku because of this outstanding issue but if it's unlikely to cause further issues I'm happy to push my changes so that everyone can see my source code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is because your password is secure and you can't call it.

You tried to patch `@other_user.password`, but it's `nil`. It's unacceptable.

So you didn't patch it and your `assert_not @other_user.reload.admin?` is green.

Try for example `"password"`.